# How to use dynamic url slugs (id) with React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to have a router that looks like this `home/{id}/{question}`. And so far, I was able to set one dynamic id by doing so:

```
export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      <Route path="/home-screen/:id" element={<Home />}>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/hom" />
      {/* <Route path='./home-screen/leaderboard' element= */}
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

And use it this way to make redirection:

```
 nav("home-screen/" + currentSelectUser?.id, {
    state: {
      user: currentSelectUser,
    },
  });
```

But how about if I want to add the id of the question as well, to have something that looks like this: `home/{id}/{question}`?

Comment: If you've already created a route with ***one*** param, what is stopping you from creating another route with ***two*** params? What have you tried? Hint, your `home/{id}/{question}` is pretty much it. What is the issue with what you've tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up this way:

```
<Route path="home/:firstId/:secondId" element={<Home />} />
```

You can make a redirection to that url like so:

```
nav("home/" + currentSelectUser?.id + "/" + currentSelectUser?.id, {
    state: {
      user: currentSelectUser,
    },
  });
```

And finally you could get them in `Home` with the help of `useParams`:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
function Home() {
  let { firstId, secondId } = useParams();
  console.log(firstId, secondId);
  return <div className="page">Hello</div>;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank for your answer, but my problem is each question will have unique id, mean  `home/:id:/:questionId`

Comment: I see. I edited my answer, give it a try.